# How to overlap two Barcharts over each other?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am creating a Bar Chart in android. I am trying to overlap two Bar Charts on each other. I am using CombinedChart provided in the [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart). But problem is both the Bar Charts are coming one beside another.

Here is the screenshot of the chart:

[image]

**Blue bars should overlap the Green bars.**

**Here is my code:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private CombinedChart combinedChart;
    protected String[] mMonths = new String[] {
            "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "June"
    };
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        combinedChart = (CombinedChart) findViewById(R.id.combinedChart);
        combinedChart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);
        combinedChart.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        combinedChart.setDrawGridBackground(false);
        combinedChart.setDrawBarShadow(false);
        combinedChart.setHighlightFullBarEnabled(false);
        Legend l = combinedChart.getLegend();
        l.setWordWrapEnabled(true);
        l.setVerticalAlignment(Legend.LegendVerticalAlignment.BOTTOM);
        l.setHorizontalAlignment(Legend.LegendHorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
        l.setOrientation(Legend.LegendOrientation.HORIZONTAL);
        l.setDrawInside(false);

        YAxis rightAxis = combinedChart.getAxisRight();
        rightAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
        rightAxis.setAxisMinimum(0f); // this replaces setStartAtZero(true)

        YAxis leftAxis = combinedChart.getAxisLeft();
        leftAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
        leftAxis.setAxisMinimum(0f); // this replaces setStartAtZero(true)

        XAxis xAxis = combinedChart.getXAxis();
        xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTH_SIDED);
        xAxis.setAxisMinimum(0f);
        xAxis.setGranularity(1f);
        xAxis.setValueFormatter(new IAxisValueFormatter() {
            @Override
            public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
                return mMonths[(int) value % mMonths.length];
            }
        });
        CombinedData data = new CombinedData();
        data.setData(generateBarData());
        combinedChart.setData(data);
        combinedChart.invalidate();
    }

    private ArrayList<BarEntry> getBar1Enteries(ArrayList<BarEntry> entries){
        entries.add(new BarEntry(1, 25));
        entries.add(new BarEntry(2, 30));
        entries.add(new BarEntry(3, 38));
        entries.add(new BarEntry(4, 10));
        entries.add(new BarEntry(5, 15));
        return  entries;
    }

    private ArrayList<BarEntry> getBar2Enteries(ArrayList<BarEntry> entries){
        entries.add(new BarEntry(1, 20));
        entries.add(new BarEntry(2, 25));
        entries.add(new BarEntry(3, 33));
        entries.add(new BarEntry(4, 5));
        entries.add(new BarEntry(5, 10));
        return  entries;
    }

    private BarData generateBarData() {

        ArrayList<BarEntry> entries1 = new ArrayList<BarEntry>();
        ArrayList<BarEntry> entries2 = new ArrayList<BarEntry>();

//        for (int index = 0; index < 12; index++) {
//            entries1.add(new BarEntry(0, getRandom(25, 25)));
//
//            // stacked
//            entries2.add(new BarEntry(0, new float[]{getRandom(13, 12), getRandom(13, 12)}));
//        }

        BarDataSet set1 = new BarDataSet(getBar1Enteries(entries1), "Bar 1");
        set1.setColor(Color.rgb(60, 220, 78));
        set1.setValueTextColor(Color.rgb(60, 220, 78));
        set1.setValueTextSize(10f);
        set1.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);

        BarDataSet set2 = new BarDataSet(getBar2Enteries(entries2), "");
        set2.setStackLabels(new String[]{"Stack 1", "Stack 2"});
        set2.setColors(new int[]{Color.rgb(61, 165, 255), Color.rgb(23, 197, 255)});
        set2.setValueTextColor(Color.rgb(61, 165, 255));
        set2.setValueTextSize(10f);
        set2.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);

        float groupSpace = 0.06f;
        float barSpace = 0.02f; // x2 dataset
        float barWidth = 0.45f; // x2 dataset
        // (0.45 + 0.02) * 2 + 0.06 = 1.00 -> interval per "group"

        BarData d = new BarData(set1, set2);
        d.setBarWidth(barWidth);

        // make this BarData object grouped
        d.groupBars(0, groupSpace, barSpace); // start at x = 0

        return d;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [Stacked BarChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Setting-Data#stacked-barchart)

```
BarEntry stackedEntry = new BarEntry(0f, new float[] { 10, 20, 30 });
```

You can also look into the example activity, which also contains a [stacked barchart.](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartExample/src/com/xxmassdeveloper/mpchartexample/StackedBarActivity.java)